# Power management issues on XUbuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, power-management, amd-graphics

I installed XUbuntu 20.04 on my new machine (AMD Ryzen™ 3 Desktop Processors with Radeon™ Vega Graphics, 3200G), but it has power management issues. For one, I can't adjust the brightness and it also wakes itself up after the display has been switched off (I have it set up to switch off the display after 5 minutes, but it turns back on and destroys my environment (I'm using XMonad and stuff)). I tried installing various drivers and even downgraded the kernel to 4.15, however that was even worse, it wouldn't switch the display off automatically after 5 minutes.

I'd like to know how can I overcome the issue?
If only I could keep the HDMI connection alive after the display has been switched off. That way, I wouldn't be left with ruined environment. At least, that's what I think.

I hope this is somewhat new hardware and the support for it is on its way.

Here is the screenshot of the Power Manager where half of the stuff is missing:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNlix.png)